# Who is your favorite VPS Provider?

Tags: vps

Who is your favorite virtual hosting provider? I'm looking for your thoughts on SliceHost, Dreamhost VPS, Linode, 1and1 VPS, etc and why you like the particular provider you named.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

I would have to say [Linode](http://www.linode.com/). Linode is built on Xen and has a great management AJAXy interface.

You can partition your hard drive directly on the web and install a different OS on each partition, boot one or the other. Of course, re-install whenever you want without filing a ticket.

They also provide a serial console that you can access through SSH or through-the-web (hence the AJAXy part).

They provide DNS service, in case you need it.

Their support is quite good and they have forums and an IRC chat where you can often get good answers.

Or if you can speak German host-europe.

Comment: Not sure if I would appreciate AJAXy experience on something like cPanel. I would rather have the comfort of knowledge that changes are made when I click on Submit.

Answer (score 11):

I like [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/) a lot.  Although their prices aren't the best for what you get, they aren't bad, and the service is wonderful.  There is nothing worse than going with a discount-bin host, and then having a problem, and finding their service staff is unresponsive.

Comment: They are very transparent. I like that.

Comment: Yep. my uptimed reports > 1 year uptime with slicehost - and excellent pro-active support. That's priceless!

Answer (score 3):

I vote for [RootBSD](http://www.rootbsd.net/), a very reliable FreeBSD hosting provider.

Answer (score 3):

I like [Gandi](http://gandi.net) (but they are in France which may not be the best option for you).

I really like their flexible architecture that let's you add server parts hourly to increase your processing power.

Comment: +1 in regards for Gandi. Myself I'm really satisfied with both their flexibility and reliability.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [TekTonic](http://tektonic.net/) for several years, and they have been extremely reliable. Inexpensive, responsive customer service, and a stable environment.

Comment: +1 I've had a VPS with TekTonic for serval years as well and overall they have been very good.

Answer (score 1):

I've just started a VPS with [A2 Hosting](http://www.a2hosting.com/).  Don't know how things will be long-term, but support has been great so far.

Comment: A2Hosting is awesome, though I've only used their shared hosting. If they had windows VPS I'd be doing VPS with them too, but unfortunately they are a Linux shop, so I can't do all my hosting with them.

Answer (score 1):

[VPS.NET](http://vps.net/) is a new cloud based VPS provider. It has been fantastic for us so far. Their staff are very helpful and competent. These are the guys behind the [uk2group](http://www.uk2group.com/) that owns many other service providers.

And you get a bunch of perks: Free DNS management that hooks up with Softlayer's anycast system. Free SSL certs. Free ISPmanager Pro for those that want a simple control panel.

Comment: I've been using VPS.net for a few months they are very good. If anyone fancies trying them out the discount code AV408K should get you 90% discount for the first month.

Answer (score 1):

I've been a happy customer of [Memset](http://www.memset.com) for about 3-4 years.  Their support staff know their stuff, their VPS are quite well priced for what you get, and they run on Xen which is extremely stable.  My current VPS with them had an uptime record of 100% throughout 2009.

Oh, and they do Windows VPSs too if that's your thing.

Answer (score 0):

I like a small startup called [LayeredTech](http://www.layeredtech.com).  I have been with them for over 3 years since they first got rolling and they have been superior in every way.

For VPS they call their solutions "The Grid Layer", and have very aggresive pricing.

Answer (score 0):

I have had really good luck with Media Temple's VPS solution called [(dv) Dedicated-Virtual](http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/dv/).

Answer (score 0):

I have been very happy with [Linode](http://linode.com). Their web interface is a breeze and includes lots of great features such as the web-based serial console, a very clean DNS configuration editor, and snazzy performance graphs. Their prices are low and their uptime high.

Answer (score 0):

I currently manage over two dozen servers at linode and slicehost. they are both excellent. You will get more for your money at Linode and the support at both companies is superb. I wouldn't trust my data to any other vps provider. (except maybe amazon ec2)

Answer (score 0):

Havent Used them but [Joyent](http://www.joyent.com) seem to have very good plans. HEAPS of bandwidth. if you can deal with opensolaris they look pretty decent. Anybody has experience?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [ContextShift](http://www.contextshift.eu). They are based in Amsterdam, and have a nice friendly support system.

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt my current VPS provider of choice is [Ultima Hosts](http://www.ultimahosts.net/windows/vps/).

They offer both Hyper-V and Parrallels Virtuozzo hosting at a very good price, their support is awesome and during setup they even loaded Windows Server 2008 R2 for me. I had my sites moved and running within 24 hours.

I highly recommend them to anyone looking for an affordable and stable VPS host.

Comment: do they do linux hosting? it seems it's all windows-based

Comment: I am not sure since I don't use Linux hosting at all. Best would be to e-mail them and check. They are quite quick with responses.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [BudgetDedicated](http://www.budgetdedicated.com/) for the last three and a half years; they're a low cost, no frills, VPS provider.  They've been rock solid (I've seen no unscheduled downtime in that period [*]), I've not had a whole lot of reason to get in touch with them, but when I have, I've had my queries answered quickly by the founder, [Erik de Bruijn](http://blog.erikdebruijn.nl/), or his brother.  They run a low carbon footprint server array, and are a fairly small operation.  Erik is pretty active in the open source and open innovation scenes; BudgetDedicated hosts the Wine .debs, and Erik is involved in the RepRap 3d printing project.

As a general point, if you are in Europe, the Netherlands is a good place to run a web server, because it is close to the main internet line running across to the US.

[*] I should note that the Wine project have seen some outages in that period, four that I know of.  AFAICT, they were all sysadmin issues.

Answer (score 0):

### Performance

This [VPS performance comparison](http://journal.uggedal.com/vps-performance-comparison) by Uggedal compares linode and several other and is worth reading