# Advice about hosting

Tags: php, hosting, web-hosting, website, drupal

I would like to ask you about hosting, maybe it's a 'stupid' question, but I'm starting to manage with this, and I need some help.

I need to find a hosting for some web sites (8 web sites created with the same template). The only thing I know is that I will need:

- knowledge of Drupal.
- PHP, MySql, XHTML, CSS and Javascript.
- develop modules and create themes.

This is my mission and I have some weeks of time (I don't know if it is enough).

I would like that you advise me about:

1. **What to do first?** How can i know
   more what i have to handle.
2. **Which hosting** you can 
   recommended to me.

I'm losing in this work, if you can help me it could be really nice for me.

PD: I look all of you are advising me quickly, I would like to clarify also that I need to do this for an Organization, then I would like also to can trust and bring me tranquility.

I also will need information about how you started with this topic, what do I need to know how manage this work (will I need to calculate the size of each web site?, how I can guess which speed it will need?, which other parameters do I need to take in consideration?)

I don't want that you solve me the entire problem, but I will need some useful information to start to work with.

Thank you, Miriam

Comment: I use liquidweb and I am very, very happy.

Comment: @warren said:
I guess part of this depends on what kind of hosting you're looking for - the links from Drupal are a good start.

Are you looking for a VPS, or dedicated, or shared? For VPS hosting, I like http://tektonic.net (see also http://serverfault.com/questions/808/who-is-your-favorite-vps-provider).

Comment: I don't know which kind of hosting should i choose.

Comment: I know, i wrote in the other post that i duplicate it because i couldn't edit anymore.

Comment: Any others ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The Drupal web site has a [list of Drupal-ready hosting services](http://drupal.org/hosting), some of which may be able to offer you support regarding Drupal administration issues, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess part of this depends on what kind of hosting you're looking for - the links from Drupal are a good start.

Are you looking for a VPS, or dedicated, or shared? For VPS hosting, I like http://tektonic.net (see also [Who is your favorite VPS Provider?](https://serverfault.com/questions/808/who-is-your-favorite-vps-provider)).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Bluehost for shared hosting. They have a simple Drupal installer script and ssh access which you will need. I have been running a Drupal site with them for a couple of years without any significant downtime.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I've been using **[MediaTemple](http://www.mediatemple.net)** for years now, and their service has been great.  Not only do they offer 1-click installs of WordPress, Drupal, and ZenCart, their custom control panel is second to none.  It easily puts Plesk and cPanel to shame.  With little setup, you can also host many domains on one MediaTemple account.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give you a more general answer; in my experience the different hosting providers differ in:

- Price, of course.
- Customer support - well, you get what you pay for :-)
- Access rights to your server. At least they should provide you with a control panel like [Plesk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plesk) or [cPanel](http://www.cpanel.net/). This is a web application that will allow you to manage your space without actually logging on to the machine.

  - advantages are ease of install of different modules (like Drupal) and different aspects of your server (like email addresses, subdomains etc.)
  - greatest disadvantage is the "bleeding edge" aspect, you won't have the most recent version available (check with them first what versions they will offer you)
- You should at least have [FTP access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) (so you can upload your themes more easily) and an online file browser to correct mistakes. With shell access (using [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)) you'll get the greatest flexibility, but some [command-line fu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/index.php) is necessary if you choose a Linux based hosting. (a great opportunity to learn some Linux though) Windows based hosting can offer you a [Remote Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) to interact with the system.
- [Shared hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_web_hosting_service) is the cheapest option: your site will be hosted with others on the same machine. If your site receives too much traffic, a [dedicated hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedicated_hosting_service) is more appropriate. However, with the lattter you'll have to manage the server on your own. (although I'm sure you can get this as an optional service)

If this all sounds too much for you you can search for a provider that delivers a ready made Drupal installation, and takes care of all the updates for you. Here you should only worry about developing your themes and modules.

Comment: Yes, it's sounds really a lot for me because it's my first time in this situation, and I only will have some weeks to say 'how I will do', or 'I can't do'.
The actual hosting is in "dreamhost.be", but they say it's really slow and in the month of September they will need to register a lot of people though their web sites (for this they need to improve this situation). 
Also, in the actual Drupal, I found really a lot of options that need to be updated. Shall I ask directly to the companies? explain my situation or they will try to get advantage of this in the price?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Logicworks offers a great solution for this, LAMP is what you may be looking for
check them out @ www.logicworks.net