# Java on Linux Web Hosting Recommendations

Tags: linux, hosting, java, vps, web

I am looking to develop a web application that will require Java. I've googled around quite a bit, but it seems that there are many options out there, lots of dubious-looking reviews sites, and not a lot of useful discussion regarding Java hosting on Linux.

- Java will be used to run a third-party database for scientific data and not for any custom programming.
- I will want SSH but not necessarily root access.
- I want responsive email, chat, and phone support.
- I want responsive network administrators that can customize and configure the software on the server as needed without me having to keep up with security patches.
- I am assuming that VPS will give me the flexibility I need with less cost than a dedicated server. Will 512MB of RAM be sufficient? I've been told that 1024MB is a better idea, but the site will have fairly low traffic.
- I've already found some VPS solutions at a trusted host that I've used for years that cost in excess of $1,800 yearly but this seems excessive.

Do you have any recommendations or general advice regarding this topic?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume this will require Tomcat, any other software you need to be supported by this said host?

Comment: if you need a VPS, try some of the places mentioned here: http://serverfault.com/questions/808/who-is-your-favorite-vps-provider/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1,800/yr = $150/mo  Normally, sure, that might be expensive for shared hosting, but you say:

> I want responsive network
>   administrators that can customize and
>   configure the software on the server
>   as needed without me having to keep up
>   with security patches.

$1,800/yr sounds like a steal for getting admin services like this which if you were to contract to someone would be the equivalent of paying them about 1 hour every month.  Everything you describe can easily be accomplished with shared or virtual system hosting.

It is the support and responsiveness that you demand which will require pay-to-play.

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick with our trusted hosting account provider. I guess there's a reason we've been happy with them so far!

Answer (score 0):

You might give Amazon EC2 a shot. You can stand up a "reserved" 32-bit linux 1.7 GB RAM for about $500-600 per year (depending on what you get).

Of course, Amazon won't manage the patches for you, and they don't know how to operate telephones.

Relatively cheap though.