# Good VPS In London?

Tags: windows, vps, rdp, performance-tuning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who is your favorite VPS Provider?](https://serverfault.com/questions/808/who-is-your-favorite-vps-provider)

I'm looking to rent a Windows VPS in (or near) London, England. I want to be able to do performance testing of our North American web services so we can establish a baseline and get real-world results of our performance modifications. Does anyone know of any recommended VPS hosts? They should run Windows (XP, 2003, 2008 - we need IE for the testing), have at least 1 gig of ram and allow RDP. Other than that anything goes.

Comment: It's similar but I'm not limited by Windows Server 2008. I basically need anything that runs IE. However, thanks for providing this as there is some valuable information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [Bytemark](http://www.bytemark.co.uk/index) or [Memset](http://www.memset.com/dedicated-servers/virtual.php), both UK based companies.  I've not used them personally, but a number of people whose opinions I trust greatly, have.

Comment: I ended up choosing Memset and so far am very impressed with them. I chose their 20Mb burstable line and was astounded as to its performance across the Atlantic. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

err..completely missed "Windows". Sorry, mate.

Isn't Linode in London? I hear people rave about them.

http://www.linode.com/speedtest/

Comment: No worries. I up-modded because I have off-topic interests in reliable *nix-based VM's in Europe also. Thank you.